# Android In-App Billing - Error Authentication is required. You need to sign into your google account

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

my Android app is using In-App Billing since april 2015 without any problems. But now this process is not working anymore. I have not changed the process of purchasing or any methods in the app.

Since my last update one week ago all my users are getting an error when they want to purchase my IAP. The app throws an error saying "Error Authentication is required. You need to sign into your google account". 
I just updated to the latest SDK-tools and my targetVersion is 23.

I have done everything I found on the Web, like checking the product id and so on.

Can anyone help me, to fix this problem?